# Java: Using the isDigit function

Tags: java

Hey all I am working on a program in Java that checks a password for a few things such as is it 8 characters, is one character Uppercase, is one lowercase, and is there a number in the password. So far I have wrote the methods for checking length, upper and lower case, with no problems. I cannot for the life of my understand why it isn't working with the isDigit().

No matter what input I throw in the method, it always returns true. Anyone see my error?

Thanks in advance!

```
public void setOneDigit(){

     int i;
     char ch;
     boolean hasNumber = false;

     for ( i = 0; i < password.length(); i++ ) {

         ch = password.charAt(i);
         if (Character.isDigit(ch));
         {    
             hasNumber = true;
         }

     }

     if(hasNumber == true)
     {
         hasOneDigit = true;
     } 
     else 
     {
          hasOneDigit = false;
     }
}
```

Comment: Remove that semicolon from the end of your `if` condition.

Comment: Ok problem solved.  Voting to close this question as off-topic because of "typographical error".

Comment: @ryanyuyu wouldn't call it typographical. It's a syntax issue.

Comment: Wow, rookie move. You stare at code long enough and go to missing simple things, thanks guys!!

Comment: @CodeWhisperer syntax issue... due to a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Classic mistake:

```
if (Character.isDigit(ch));
     {    
         hasNumber = true;
     }
```

has to be

```
if (Character.isDigit(ch))
     {    
         hasNumber = true;
     }
```